# Is it possible to instantiate a new VM on GCP using Google Cloud Function and Regional Managed Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, high-availability

basically what I trying to do is creating a message on Pub/Sub that triggers a GCF which creates a instance from a Regional Managed Instance Group in whatever available zone it has at the time.

The issue I'm trying to solve here is a rather recurrent ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED which the regional MIG deals with.

Is this solution possible? I've tried using [createInstances method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.regionInstanceGroupManagers.html#createInstances) but Logging just states PRECONDITION_FAILED.

The code snippet I'm using is as follows:

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
def launch_vm(project, region, igm, body)
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
    response = service.regionInstanceGroupManagers()\
               .createInstances(
                   project=project,
                   region=region,
                   instanceGroupManager=igm,
                   body=body)
    return response.execute()

request_body = {"instances":[{"name": "testinstance"}]}

launch_vm('project-name', 'us-central1', 'instace-group-name', request_body)
```

####### EDIT :
I just found out what happened, when I tried on another project with a recently created instance group, I found out that instance redistribution was enabled, which can NOT be the case as with the response from the CLI:

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.create-instance) CreateInstances can be used only when instance redistribution is disabled (set to NONE).`

I checked out the instance redistribution check and now it works wonders :) Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Can you share how do you call the createInstance method? It could explain your precondition failed error.

Comment: I editied my question to include the code I'm using, could you take a look again? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I wonder whether you're hitting these [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/working-with-managed-instances#adding_instances_with_specific_names)? I don't understand the problem. If the MIG is unable to create an instance in a zone, isn't it the MIG's job to retry?

Comment: I've tried using the gcloud tool with `gcloud compute instance-groups managed create-instance instance-group --region=us-central1 --instance=instance-name` and it works! Which indicates to me that my usage of the API is faulty, there's something missing :( do you have any idea what it may be ?

Comment: Good argument! Try appending `--log-http` to that `gcloud` command and you'll be given details of the underlying call(s). Alternatively, you can use APIs Explorer to make the REST API call directly. Either mechanism should help you identify errors or omissions. See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/createInstances

Comment: By the way, you probably want to pull `discovery.build` out of the function (or as part of some class) so that the service isn't rebuilt on every invocation.

Comment: If I find some time, I'll have a look at repro'ing.

Comment: By the way.... your invocation is incorrect.... you want `service.regionInstanceGroupManagers().createInstances()` right? Let me know if that addresses it. If not, I'll take a look

Comment: @DazWilkin, you're correct, I accidentally forgot it when writing this question, that's my bad.

Comment: In another note, after I made the CLI command, the API suddenly started working as intended and now the same piece of code works... Maybe the CLI command forces some sort of config that I may have overlooked on the instance group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to `createInstance`:

```
import os

from googleapiclient import discovery


PROJECT = os.environ["PROJECT"]
REGION = os.environ["REGION"]
NAME = os.environ["NAME"]

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')

def launch_vm(project,region, name, body):
    rqst = service.regionInstanceGroupManagers().createInstances(
                   project=project,
                   region=region,
                   instanceGroupManager=name,
                   body=body)
    return rqst.execute()


body = {
    "instances": [
        {
            "name": "testinstance"
        }
    ]
}

launch_vm(PROJECT, REGION, NAME, body)
```